# Laravel Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart associate() doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my **Laravel** I'm using [this shoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart)  .

When I add one product to my shopping cart I want to have `associate()` with `App\Product` Model .

This is my code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // store product information to Cart
    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)
      ->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect(route('cart.index'))
      ->with('success_message', 'محصول با موفقیت به سبد اضافه شد');
}
```

But when I want to access model `$item->model->id` in view I get this error :

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\digikala\resources\views\cart.blade.php)
```

Edit :

my cart view (`cart.blade.php`) codes :

```
  <table border="1" class="table">
      @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
        {{ $item->model->id }}
      @endforeach
    </table>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing is wrong with your `store` method. How about the `cart.index`? Can you share us the logic behind it. It would be nice if you can share the `cart.blade.php` code as well.

Comment: @krisanalfa if you mean cart home `view` file . i added it to question pls see **Edit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could solve this problem .

Everything was about `$request` data inside `store()` method .

Mistakes were in the form of adding **product** to **cart** .

I did not post the **product ID** correctly to the `store()` method .

If anyone had this problem in the future I hope to test `$request` first by this code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //verify the submitted product
    $product = Product::where('slug', $request->input('slug'))->first();
    //check if  item is available
    if($product === null){
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('error', 'Unable to add product to cart');
    }
    else{

        Cart::add($product->id, $product->title,  1,  $product->price)
            ->associate('App\Product');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success', 'Product added to cart');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I also retrieve my products via the using slug because i'd like to protect the items unique id, Just ensure that you use the primary key for the cart id